filterScope_values in Apex class without SOAP and REST API
I need to access filterScope_values in Apex without making SOAP or REST API callouts. While it's possible to do this with SOAP and REST API callouts, I'm unable to make these callouts from the Apex class I've built. The reason for this limitation is that I've created a 2GP-managed package, and adding a REST API callout would require me to provide justifications for doing so.
Once I receive filterScope_values, then after I'll be able to run the below query.

SELECT column_name FROM table_name USING SCOPE filterScope_value

